# Why is centering and alignment not working in bootstrap 4?

Tags: jquery, html, css

**EDIT** I found out what the issue is, Code Pen is using the wrong url for bootstrap 4. Thanks to the people who have answered already.

This is my code

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="quote-box text-center">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col quote">
          asdasdasdsa
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row align-items-center">
        <div class="col text-center">
          <button class="btn btn-primary social">asasas</button>
          <button class="btn btn-primary social">asasasas</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-5">
        </div>
        <div class="col text center">
          <button class="btn btn-primary"></button>
        </div>
      </div>      
    </div>
</div>
```

The codepen is this, https://codepen.io/msrashid/pen/EboJoq

The row align text center is not making the column center vertically.

The text center is not making the buttons center in the columns.

Not sure what the issue is.

Comment: I often find with these issues the best thing for testing is to add borders. Try adding a border to the `col` class eg `.col { border: 1px solid red; }` and you'll see what the issue is :)

Comment: Thanks. That helps. But the buttons are still not centered in the columns, and I'm not sure why my border is outside the box it's nested in.

Comment: Your box isn't the full width - it's not the text that's unaligned, but the columns themselves :)

Comment: I see. I used padding instead of putting in a specific height and width for the box which worked. I kinda get where you're coming from, but I'm not totally sure why it's working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your centralisation is indeed working. The problem is that your columns aren't occupying the full width, and thus don't *appear* to be centralised.

In order to fix this, you need to make use of the **[Bootstrap column classes](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/)**. Where you have `col` classes, you're looking to use `col-1` through `col-12`. A row always has a total of 12 columns, so you always need to total up to that.

Your row `? - 5 - ?` cannot 'centralise', as `7` (12 - 5) cannot be wholly divided by two (it would be `3.5` on either side of the 5). As such, I've considered each segment to be an independent row in the following example:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="quote-box text-center">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 quote">
        asdasdasdsa
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row align-items-center">
      <div class="col-12 text-center">
        <button class="btn btn-primary social">asasas</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary social">asasasas</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 text center">
        <button class="btn btn-primary"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I followed your advice. I made each column-4 which adds up to twelve, but as you can see from this codepen that the buttons are still not centered. https://codepen.io/msrashid/pen/EboJoq

Comment: Your CodePen shows the buttons centered. If you're talking about the green borders overlapping the edges, that's due to the negative margins applied by `.col-`. You need to offset this by wrapping each of the columns inside a row with `class="row"`. This is already demonstrated in my above example, but is missing from your CodePen.

Comment: That's not what I'm aiming for anyways. I want the buttons to be on the same level but a little far apart. But you see it fixed now because I added the proper bootstrap link. Codepen has an incorrect version of the bootstrap 4 link embedded.